# Download image from firebase to external sd Card using url

Tags: android, firebase, url, uri, android-external-storage

i have uploaded image file in my firebase. I have stored url to firebase-database. During storing process,To get url i used `Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();` 
Now i want to download that image file from that url when button is clicked and want to store that image file into specific folder of sd card let say "New Folder"
help me with following code....

```
FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
StorageReference httpsReference;

mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
httpsReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(downloadUri);

Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //what??
    }
});
```

Comment: have you looked at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all create database ref and a File like this

```
StorageReference downloadRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Wall/" + category
            + "/" + wall_id + ".jpg");
    File localFile = null;
    try {
        String fileName = wall_id + ".jpg";
        localFile = new File();//create your file with desired path
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

than call getFile on that reference like this

```
downloadRef.getFile(localFile)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {}
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Toast.makeText(WallOptionActivity.this, "Download failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

the file will be saved to given path.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement [FileDownloadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask); see this [example](https://gist.github.com/jirawatee/6dd86cb790c1b71183f5aad21d94b82d).

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the SD card, while may need to request permission `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, in order to access that path. eg. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Picasso for your purpose. To save image on external disk you can use following:

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
    .load(ImageUrl)
    .into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            try {
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/yourDirectory");

                if (!myDir.exists()) {
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                }

                String name = new Date().toString() + ".jpg";
                myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                out.flush();
                out.close();                        
            } catch(Exception e){
                // some action
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        }
    }
);
```

[From here](http://square.github.io/picasso/) you can download this library.
Don't forget to add permission in manifest file